# Angular - add new row to mat-table when using FormControlArray as dataSource

Tags: angular

Below is my stackblitz example where it shown all companies and their respective contacts. Iterating through each company and binding contacts to mat-table. So far it is working.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-riepzk-2k5mcv?file=app%2Ftable-basic-example.html

But I need to add a new row to mat-table for their respective company. I have implemented logic to push the new contact to existing Form Array collection in addRow method. but it is not effecting on mat-table, but I able to see the updated contact in 'form.value'.

Here i have couple of questions

1. Since I am using formarray and binding each collection to mat-table, is this the right way of implementing the code when comparing with normal way of binding single dataSource to mat-table?
2. When binding single data source to mat-table, we used to initialize data source like dataSource = new MatTableDataSource() and then bind data to dataSource.data property in type script file and In .html page we update datasource to [dataSource] property of mat-table like *mat-table [dataSource] = "datasource"*.
   But how it was the case of looping through the form array and binding data to [dataSource] property in html. Since the data is dynamic and we can not intialize the dataSource to MatTableDataSource directly in .ts file. (OR) please let me know if there is a way of implementation

Comment: 1) you can use this kind of binding
2) with #table directive you can in your component access table properties with @ViewChild selector. With that, you can access this.table.datasource and change it's structure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`MatTable` doesn't automatically re-render when using an array as the datasource... you need to call the `renderRows()` method on the table to update the table in the view.

> Since the table optimizes for performance, it will not automatically
>   check for changes to the data array. Instead, when objects are added,
>   removed, or moved on the data array, you can trigger an update to the
>   table's rendered rows by calling its renderRows() method.

https://material.angular.io/components/table/overview#1-write-your-mat-table-and-provide-data

---

Get `QueryList` with all `MatTables` in view

```
 @ViewChildren(MatTable) _matTables
```

Pass `i` to `addRow()`

```
 (click)="addRow(c.controls.contacts, i)
```

Accept `i` and call `renderRows()` in your `addRow()` method for the `MatTable` index your are adding a row to.

```
addRow(elem: FormArray, i) {
    console.log('add row');
    console.log(elem);

    elem.push(
      this.fb.group({
        id: [0],
        contactName: ['kris'],
        emailId: ['kris@gmail.com'],
        adminAgent: [false],
        collateralAgent: [false],
        trusteeAgent: [false],
      })
    );
   this._matTables['_results'][i].renderRows()
  }
```

**Stackblitz**

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-riepzk-ztcclu?embed=1&file=app/table-basic-example.ts

Answer (score 0):

Use following two lines.

```
this.datasource.data.push(<newObject>);
this.datasource.data = this.designationDetails.data.slice();
```