# Angular refresh Table (dataSource)

Tags: angular, typescript

object.component.html

```
<div class="mat-elevation-z8">
        <mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource">

            <ng-container *ngFor="let disCol of displayedColumns; let colIndex = index" matColumnDef={{disCol}}>
                <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef [appSort]="dataSource.data" data-order="desc" data-name="id">{{disCol}}</mat-header-cell>
                <mat-cell *matCellDef="let data "> {{data[disCol]}}
                </mat-cell>
            </ng-container>



            <mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></mat-header-row>
            <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></mat-row>
        </mat-table>

        <mat-paginator [pageSizeOptions]="[2, 10, 20]" showFirstLastButtons
            aria-label="Select page of formular elements">
        </mat-paginator>
        
    </div>
<button (click)="openDialogAdd()" mat-mini-fab color="success">
        <mat-icon>add</mat-icon>
    </button>
```

data-service.ts

```
addEntryToList(entry: ContactListEntry) {
    FORMULARLIST.push(entry);
  }
```

object.component.ts

```
  displayedColumns: string[] = ["id", "name", "vorname", "mobileNumber", "secondMobileNumber", "email", "secondEmail", "roomNumber", "task", "Notes", "Edit", "Delete"];
  dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<ContactListEntry>(FORMULARLIST);

  @ViewChild(MatPaginator, { static: true }) paginator: MatPaginator;
  @ViewChild(MatSort) sort: MatSort;

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
    setTimeout(() => this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator);

    this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;

  }





 openDialogAdd() {
    this.dialogService.open(PopupWindowComponent, { minWidth: "700px", minHeight: "400px", /*hasBackdrop: false,*/ });
  }
```

I want that if i add an new user with that the dataSource refresh and the Table render that i can see the new  item.

I need to know how to tell the table that I have added a new item so that the table is updated and the new item is displayed

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Angular - add new row to mat-table when using FormControlArray as dataSource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53721341/angular-add-new-row-to-mat-table-when-using-formcontrolarray-as-datasource)

Comment: It doesnt work. I dont know i try it with this this.myTable.renderRows(); but it dont work